# DNN9 Google index coverage 5xx error on default.html

Tags: search, dotnetnuke, sitemap

I have a DNN9 site that is using friendly URLs. I've resolved all my Google index coverage issues except for one. Google is returning an index coverage error for http://mysite/default.html, which doesn't exist. Not sure of the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would just throw a default.html file out there that has a redirect to the root of your website.

Contents would be something like:

```
<script>
window.location = "http://mysite";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, DNN does not allow you to have a page named default.html.

Comment: I know this, but you can create a file on the web server with that name.